# What's the word for getting approval for an invoice?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word to use when I need to ask to get some approval for an invoice from my boss?

"Approval" means he agrees with it, but his signature is used to get someone to actually pay it. What's that process called?

Comment: Fill in an expense claim form?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more suitable for [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: If you are asking for a word for it, you could say you are asking your boss to _authorise_ the invoice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with English as a language.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It does, now that Andrew's edited it.

Comment: Unfortunately @Anu has deleted his comment which corroborated the edit.

Comment: I don't understand why *approval* isn't the right word in the first place. *Can I get your* ***approval***? It doesn't necessarily only mean *personal* agreement. In a business context, it means a signature.

Answer (score 1):

In this context *approve* means *provide authorisation for the required action*, not *agree with the idea that the invoice should be paid*.

Depending on the organisation, approving an invoice could mean a signature on paper, pressing a button on-screen in a computerised accounting system, sending an email, or perhaps just a nod of the head if it is a family business rather than a major corporation.

So you would say to the boss, "Can you please approve this invoice?" After they've signed you could then tell somebody else, "The boss approved this."